# How do I avoid making multiple queries to MongoDB for my python script

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, pymongo, database-performance

Help me solve this problem and improve my script. This is a long post, please bear with me. I am writing a small web app which helps users to maintain wishlist of products they are interested. I am using MongoDB to store the data and Python Tornado as server.

There are two collections in database, one for storing product details and another to maintain user details. Whenever user adds a new product link, the url will be added to products collection and its object id will be added user's document. Its actually a list and to which it will be added.

so, a typical document in product collection will be:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("53a2bfcfa7603606c2765342"),
  name: "Nexus 7 from Google (7-Inch, 16 GB, Black)",
  url: "http://www.amazon.com/Nexus-Google-7-Inch-Black-Tablet/dp/B00DVFLJDS/",
  base_price: 222,
  current_price: 213.96,
}
```

and that of user's will be:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("539c4adea760360886d7ef02"),
  email_id: "johnappleseed@apple.com",
  tracked_products: [
    ObjectId("53a2bfcfa7603606c2765342"),
    ObjectId("53a2d2ada7603606c2765344"),
    ObjectId("53a2d294a7603606c2765343")
  ]
}
```

Now I have written a cron job which runs once everyday and updates the `current_price`. If `current_price` goes below `base_price` I have to send an alert to the user. This is were it gets tricky for me. I want to send the email even if any one of the product price changes.

A simple but inefficient way will be, check price and if there is a change in price then add a new value in product document. May be `alert: yes` and then loop through all users, loop through each of object ids of tracked products, if any document matching these object ids has alert field as yes then add the user email to email queue. And another cron job to reset alert. The code will be

```
email_id_queue = []
for product in product.collection:
    # price changed? if yes, then update
    # add/update alert: yes
    # ...
    product.collection.save(product)

for user in users.collection:
    for product_id in user['tracked_products']:
        product = products_collection.find({'_id': product_id})
        if product.get('alert', None):
            email_id_queue.append(user['email_id'])
            break

# send emails to all of those who are in email_id_queue
```

I found above implementation not efficient and I am sure there could be many ways to improve it. As now I have following solution, every time I find a product whose price is changed, I add that to a separate list. And when I loop through the user, I will just check whether it has any of those object ids are not.

```
email_id_queue = []
price_changed_products = set()

for product in product.collection:
    # price changed? if yes, then update
    # ...
    # ...
    price_changed_products.add(product['_id'])
    product.collection.save(product)

for user in users.collection:
    if set(user['tracked_products']) & price_changed_products:
        email_id_queue.append(user[email_id])

# send emails to all of those who are in email_id_queue
```

A user on reddit suggested me an alternative. I will maintain another collection, may be called `trackers`. This collection will have product_ids and the object ids of user document of who are tracking it. May be something like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("77a2bfcfa7603606c2765399"),
    product_id: ObjectId("53a2bfcfa7603606c2765342"),
    subscribers: ['user1@email.com', 'user2@email.com', 'user3@email.com']
}
```

Now whenever there is a price change, I will add list of subscribers of that product to email queue. This won't require any extra looping. I can do this whenever I am checking for new prices (the earlier for loop).

However if I want to send other notifications also, like Chrome alerts, iOS push etc, above won't work. So I thought lets keep track of `user_id` instead of their emails. Something like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("77a2bfcfa7603606c2765399"),
    product_id: ObjectId("53a2bfcfa7603606c2765342"),
    subscribers: [ObjectId("12a2bfcfa7603606c2765399"), ObjectId("14a2bfcfa7603606c2765399"), ObjectId("56a2bfcfa7603606c2765399")]
}
```

And then query the DB again with the object ids of users and send notifications. So finally it will be:

```
user_ids_queue = set()

for product in product.collection:
    # price changed? if yes, then update
    # ...
    # ...
    # find the subscribers:
    product_document = db.trackers.find_one({'product_id': product['_id']})
    user_ids_queue.add(product_document['trackers'])
    product.collection.save(product)

# now send notifications to each of those users:

for user_id in user_ids_queue:
    user_document = db.users.find_one({'_id': user_id})
    # now send notifications:
    add_to_email_queue(user_document['email'])
    add_to_chrome_queue(user_document['chrome_id'])
    add_to_ios_queue(user_document['ios_push_id'])
    # etc
```

But can I make it even better? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This might be better placed in codereview.stackexchange

Comment: I cannot post on codereview: "Questions containing broken code or asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. Such questions may be suitable for Stack Overflow or Programmers."

Comment: Why can't you add subscribers to product collection itself instead of creating another tracker collection. So that your work gets done while iterating over products. Don't forget 16MB document limit.

Comment: well yes, thats one way to do it. However it wouldn't it become to messy to keep chrome notification data, ios push and emails? and also it will be redundant cos a user can add multiple products. Thats why I thought its better to maintain separate collection.